# EGit Synchronize Workspace sometimes shows unaltered files

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I recently switched a few projects from svn to git using `git svn clone`. But now I sometimes encounter the following issue:

When using *Team -> Synchronize Workspace* on my project, there are some files shown marked as changed, but sometimes unchanged files are shown as well. I did not change the files myself, there is no `>` next to them in the Synchronize View (see picture), and, last but not least, `git status` does not show them.

[image: Picture of Synchronize View on Imgur]

Usually, when I restart Eclipse, the files are not shown anymore, but sometimes other files reappear. Is there any known solution to this?

I am btw sure that it is not because the line ending are changed - they are CRLF in all files and do not get changed at any point.

Comment: I have seen bugs in the eGit plugin, so this might be the explanation.  Whenever eGit would act up, we always used `git status` as the ultimate authority about what was really the state of a branch.

Comment: Using `git status` seems reasonable, though I hope for another solution because it is more convenient to only use EGit and stay in Eclipse, at least for some colleagues used to svn and Eclipse.

Comment: I have seen every stranger behavior in eGit, such as the plugin allowing you to switch branches while your workspace is dirty.

Comment: Now I'm bewildered - I started learning git not long ago and thought that was normal behavior? I just tested it:
`git init; touch foo; git add foo; git commit -m 'foo added'; git checkout -b new-branch; echo 'newline'>>foo; git checkout master` creates the new repo, changes to a branch, changes the file, and then I can checkout the master branch without problems.

Comment: You committed your work _before_ switching branches.

Comment: Well, I created new-branch and checked it out with a clean working directory, but then I changed foo (by adding newline) and then checked out master. This works without git telling me I'm not allowed to do this or something like that; and when I use `git status` after that, I'm told I have now checked out master and there are unstaged changes in file foo (which I changed while having checked out new-branch).